# Problem with printing the correct number of same characters.RLE in C

Tags: c, run-length-encoding

I am having difficulties printing out the correct number of character in a RLE program. I have already made it work with arrays and Im looking for a different approach.Here is the code :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char elem,elem1;
    int n=1;
    while ((elem=getchar())!=EOF && elem!='\n'){
        if ((elem1=getchar())==elem){
            n++;
        }
        printf("%d%c",n,elem);
        n=1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

For example when I enter --> ttyyy the output is 2t2y1y. Already tried adding an else statement but it never actually enters the statement.Output should have been 2t3y.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling getchar() twice in one loop iteration (once in the while condition, once in the if condition)?

Comment: what should the output be?

Comment: Output should have been 2t3y.

Comment: Im calling getchar twice because Im reading the next character, I did not find another way to do it.

Comment: My guess is that your program will never show a count bigger than 2. Can you confirm? E.g., test with `tttttt`

Comment: That is true. N never becomes greater than 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

Basically, we count all characters as long as it's the same one as before. When the character changes, we print the char along with the older counter and set our counter back to 1.

- `old_elem` holds the last character
- `elem` holds the current character

(we set old_elem to some  initial value so that we can check whether it's the first char encountered)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char elem;
    char old_elem = '$';
    int n=1;
    while ((elem=getchar())!=EOF && elem!='\n'){
        if (elem==old_elem) { 
            n++; 
        }
        else { 
            if ( old_elem!='$') { printf("%d%c",n,elem); } 
            n=1; 
        }
        old_elem = elem;
    }
    printf("%d%c\n",n,old_elem);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input:**

> ttyyy

**Output:**

> 2t3y

Comment: This is correct with a small edit , in the if statement it should be printf("%d%c",n,old_elem) instead.Thank you na sai kala!

Comment: @alex01011 haha... kalhmera! :)